# How to delete a row from DynamoDB with Amplify?

Tags: javascript, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to run this with errors:

deletepair = async () => {

```
    const removePair = {
       id: 'id'
       pairIndex: 1,
    };

    try {
       await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.removePairItem, {input: removePair}));
       console.log('done')
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err)
    }   
  }
```

When i run deletepair() i get the error:

```
  error:  TypeError: Must provide Source. Received: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your schema file contains the `Mutation` type twice.  Try changing it to look something like this:

```
type Mutation {
  addPairToItem(input: AddPairToItemInput!): Users!
  removePairFromItem(input: RemovePairInput!): Users!
}
```

Comment: That pushed successfully! So silly of me. Thanks sooo much! I'm just going to test it to see if the indexed row does indeed get removed and report back